# slick2d image gets lost

Tags: java, image, lwjgl, slick2d

I have a problem with the Slick 2D API.
I am building a little Zelda like 2d game. So i have built a little testing world. The world consists of chunks which have an image as floor. Then inside the render method the first all chunks are drawn, and after the meshes are drawn on top of it.

Mainly I use the Image class of slick to draw and modify images on the screen.

I load the images inside the init() method. In the render() method I call image.draw(x,y) to draw the image. But it seems that the last chunk drawn is not drawn. Instead a black hole appears.

As a test I tried to write the specific image to the hard disc. It succeeds from the init method, but when I save the image from the render method I get a black image.

Somehow the image gets lost after the init method, but the other images remain.

Extra information: When starting to build the game I kept in mind to seperate game logic from system dependent tasks. That's why I have an interface for some basic image manipulation. The game logic uses that interface. Then I used java2d for rendering, but the performance was poor. Now I switched to slick and I wrote an adapter and it works fine except from "world hole".

Here is the interface:

```
public interface ImageRGBA {
public static final int CHANNEL_A = 3;
public static final int CHANNEL_R = 2;
public static final int CHANNEL_G = 1;
public static final int CHANNEL_B = 0;
public static final int CHANNEL_COUNT = 4;

public int getHeight();
public int getWidth();

public void setPixel(int x, int y, int channel, byte value);
public void setPixel(int x, int y, byte[] argb);

public byte getPixel(int x, int y, int channel);
public byte[] getPixel(int x, int y);

public int getPixelARGB(int x, int y);
public void setPixelARGB(int x, int y, int argb);

public void insertImage(int x, int y, ImageRGBA image);
}
```

And the slick implementation:

```
public class SlickImageAdapter implements ImageRGBA {
private final Image image;

public SlickImageAdapter(Image image){
    this.image = image;
}

@Override
public int getHeight() {
    return this.image.getHeight();
}

@Override
public int getWidth() {
    return this.image.getWidth();
}

@Override
public void setPixel(int x, int y, int channel, byte value) {
    Color color = this.image.getColor(x,y);
    int[] components = new int[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_COUNT];
    components[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_R] = color.getRed();
    components[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_G] = color.getGreen();
    components[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_B] = color.getBlue();
    components[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_A] = color.getAlpha();

    components[channel] = value - Byte.MIN_VALUE;

    try {
        Graphics graphics = this.image.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(new Color(
                components[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_R],
                components[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_G],
                components[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_B],
                components[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_A]
                ));
        graphics.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
       // graphics.destroy();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void setPixel(int x, int y, byte[] argb) {
    try {
        Graphics graphics = this.image.getGraphics();
        graphics.setColor(new Color(
                argb[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_R] - Byte.MIN_VALUE,
                argb[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_G] - Byte.MIN_VALUE,
                argb[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_B] - Byte.MIN_VALUE,
                argb[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_A] - Byte.MIN_VALUE
        ));
        graphics.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
        //graphics.destroy();
    } catch (SlickException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public byte getPixel(int x, int y, int channel) {
    return this.getPixel(x,y)[channel];
}

@Override
public byte[] getPixel(int x, int y) {
    Color color = this.image.getColor(x,y);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_COUNT];
    bytes[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_R] = (byte) (color.getRedByte() + Byte.MIN_VALUE);
    bytes[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_G] = (byte) (color.getGreenByte() + Byte.MIN_VALUE);
    bytes[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_B] = (byte) (color.getBlueByte() + Byte.MIN_VALUE);
    bytes[ImageRGBA.CHANNEL_A] = (byte) (color.getAlphaByte() + Byte.MIN_VALUE);
    return bytes;
}

@Override
public int getPixelARGB(int x, int y) {
    ImageManager imageManager = Device.getDevice().getImageManager();
    return imageManager.byteArrayToIntARGB(this.getPixel(x,y));
}

@Override
public void setPixelARGB(int x, int y, int argb) {
    ImageManager imageManager = Device.getDevice().getImageManager();
    this.setPixel(x,y, imageManager.intARGBToByteArray(argb));
}

@Override
public void insertImage(int x, int y, ImageRGBA image) {
    try{
        Graphics graphics = this.image.getGraphics();
        graphics.drawImage(((SlickImageAdapter) image).getImage(), x, y);
        //graphics.destroy();
    }catch (SlickException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Image getImage(){
    return this.image;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't call the Graphics.flush() method after manipulating the image.